# Add ROI to 1D image (intensity plot etc.)

Tags: dm-script

Try to add ROI of determined position to 1D image (intensity plot, or line scan proflie).  It does not work, could not find the function by google, is there correct codes?

```
number d0, d1
image spc:=getFrontImage()
spc.getSize(d0,d1)

imagedisplay imgdisp = spc.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

ROI roi_1 = NewROI()

ROISetRectangle( roi_1, 0, 100,d1 , 200 )

imgdisp.ImageDisplayAddROI( roi_1)

imagedisplaysetroiselected(imgdisp, roi_1,1)
```

Comment: try ROISetRange( roi_1, 100, 200 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact error message when running your code is:

[image: Error]

This very accurately tells you the problem: Not all types of ROIS (Rectangle, Line, Lasso, Point,...) are suitable for all kind of displays. In particular, you can't draw a rectangle-ROI on a LinePlot display.

In fact, LinePlot displays support a single type of ROI: Range-ROIs.

So, the code for you problem is:

```
image spc:=getFrontImage()
imagedisplay imgdisp = spc.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

ROI roi_1 = NewROI()

ROISetRange( roi_1, 100, 200 )

imgdisp.ImageDisplayAddROI( roi_1)

imagedisplaysetroiselected(imgdisp, roi_1,1)
```